# Button Override - Redirect on Create of Custom Record

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, redirect, button-overrides

When a user creates a new record I want to either A) redirect them to a page that says "success" or B) redirect them back to the home page with an alert that says "success".

I don't see the "save" button as an option to edit under the custom object buttons/links/actions. I can edit the "new" button but they are asking for a new VFP or Lightning Page.

Is there a quicker way then having to code out a new page with an apex redirect?

Comment: It's kind of overkill, but you could do something like this with a screen flow.

Comment: Overriding the new button will override the standard page with layouts, so I don't think you want that. What @pchittum said would be your best bet.

Comment: @pchittum I could do this with a flow but I would still have to replace the "New" button with a visualforce page that calls a flow...right? Or is there a different way?

Comment: VF or Lightning Component could be an option. Is this a one-off, or is it something you want to have happen globally?

Comment: @pchittum globally. it's on the record creation of one of our main object.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a screen flow and showing the user the success page upon finish. I also redirected the user back to their homepage once complete.

Hope this helps someone!